# limit of a serie of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to calculate $\sum_{n\to +\infty} \frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{5^n z^{n+1}}$. Using wolfram alpha I found $\frac{-5}{z^2-3z+1}$ but I don't understand how to get this result.
I know that this serie converges iff $r1<z<r2$ where $r1$ and $r2$ are the roots of $z^2-3z+1$. I don't know how to connect all this facts. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a (almost) geometric series. When it converges, we have:\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{5^nz^{n+1}}&=\frac1z\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{(1+z)^2}{5z}\right)^n\\&=\frac1z\cdot\frac1{1-\frac{(1+z)^2}{5z}}\\&=\frac1{z-\frac{(1+z)^2}5}\\&=\frac5{5z-(1+z)^2}\\&=-\frac5{z^2-3z+1}.\end{align}